# Flutter Windows build flavor

Tags: windows, flutter

I have a Flutter Windows app,and I want to build two flavor (dev and prod).
But i don't konw how to build for windows.
Is anybody know?
Please tell me how to configure.

Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can build your app with a dart-define that sets the flavor:

```
flutter build --dart-define FLAVOR=prod
```

In the app, you get it as a constant variable:

```
const String flavor = String.fromEnvironment("FLAVOR", defaultValue: "dev");
```

Note that "fromEnvironment" is related to the build environment here and has nothing to do with "normal" environment variables.

The fact that a dart-define is available as a constant value enables so-called tree shaking: conditions based on such constant values are optimized out of release builds. This is quite similar to what you would do in C / C++ with an `ifdef` in the resultin binary, while everything that is not "shaken out" is still made sure to compile.

Answer (score -3):

this is a rather tricky one...

```
bool devModeEnabled = true;
    
    if(devModeEnabled){
    
    //do dev mode stuff
    
    }else{
    
    //do other stuff
    
    }
```